# Не могу получить список элементов по xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

В общем нужно получить список элементов найденных по xpath, что бы в дальнейшем сравнивать значения и считать количество.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

o = Options()
o.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=o)
driver.get('https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all')
driver.execute_script("window.editor.setValue('SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City = \"London\"')")
buttonRun = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button")
buttonRun.click()
count = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr[td[contains(text(), 'London')]]")
print(count)
```

В браузере по этому xpath находится 6 элементов, но когда запускаю тест приходит пустой массив. Еще заметил если пользоваться find_element иногда возвращается 1 элемент. Может как то через скрипты можно добраться до элементов, все перерыл, не пойму.

Comment: После нажатия кнопки таблица появляется не сразу поэтому после `buttonRun.click()` нужно добавить `time.sleep(1)`

Comment: блин, а  я ведь ставил слипы изначально, сейчас выставил больше задержку и заработало...